# How can i model a system with many functionalities using a UML activity diagram?

Tags: uml

I'm currently reverse engineering a ticketing system (a ticket booth system with human operator), in order to create a technical manual. 
What I want to do was a flowdown from all the functionalities modeled as a workflow from the user PoV using a UML activity diagram. The objetive in this is to first lay the workflow of the user, to than specify all the interfaces/communications with databases and central systems and all the classes as class diagrams, regarding the functionalities displayed on the activity diagram.

The problem is that the system has so many options, like buy ticket, recover ticket, client info, shift managemen... the first problem i got is when i got to the main screen activity there are so many branches that i dont know if i could use a Decision point on the activity diagram.

Anyone can shed some knowledge here? Thanks to all. Cheers.

Comment: Feels like this might be a bit too broad. Try starting with use cases and work out the flows from there.

Comment: The flow I was building was like: Start - login (with 3 login conditions) - Home screen (as a state) - then a bifurcation to more than 20 functionalities... Should i do a general usecase with the usecases being those 20 functions, and then activity diagram for each of those? Thank you

Comment: Don't do the "general" use case, only use cases for the major functions. Then do an activity diagram for each use case describing the different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Even the system is already there the approach for building the model should be pretty much the same as if you were doing the analysis from the start. The main difference is you refer to how the system is actually used, however it's also a good occasion to discover the pain points in the current system.

Your use cases, scenarios etc will be based on what the system currently does.

Don't try documenting a complex system with just one diagram or even one type of a diagram. This approach will most likely fail. In a best case scenario you'll end up with something but it'll be difficult to impossible to read and comprehend.